# What topic in algebraic manipulation does this fall under?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

My professor discussed in Algebra a manipulation of equations

$$x + y = 4\\
x^2 + y^2 = 12$$

to get $xy$.

I find that $xy$ is 2.

But what topic does it fall under? If I search in Google about such problems, I don't know what keywords would lead me to right stuff. I want to know if such problems belong to a formal field. Thank you.

Comment: This is your eleventh question here. Could you consider learning MathJax?

Comment: The topic is solving systems of polynomial equations over a field (which you haven't specified here).

Answer (score 2):

Symmetric polynomials, I think.

More concrete: elementary symmetric polynomials:

$$12=x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy=16-2xy.$$

Comment: OP's question is admittedly unclear and broad, but I don't think that this answers it; the question is about the field of mathematics under which solving polynomial systems falls under, rather than a solution to this particular system.

Comment: Edit looks good. OP might also be interested in [systems of polynomial equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_polynomial_equations), more broadly.

Comment: @Romain S Yes, you are right. Thanks all!

Comment: Systems of polynomial equations actually feels fitting. I am not really after the symmetry of the polynomials but that, values are given to systems of polynomials rather than variables and you have to solve another polynomial. Like instead of being given an x and y to find z, we are given polynomials. Thank you for the answer.